# Aptitude: list security updates

Tags: ubuntu, security, update, aptitude

I'm trying to list and display some info about available security updates on Ubuntu server.

I would use the following command, where `?archive(security)` filters packages that contain `security` in their archive, while `%t` shows the archive:

```
aptitude search "?upgradable ?archive(security)" -F "%p %t %v %V" --disable-columns
```

I found this issue: in the output, there are packages pertaining to the `updates` archive as well as to the `security` archive. See the following excerpt:

```
xwayland                      xenial-updates
xwayland:i386                 xenial-updates
xwayland-hwe-16.04            xenial-security,xenial-updates
xwayland-hwe-16.04:i386       xenial-security,xenial-updates
```

Am I making a mistake or missing some understanding of the command or the system?

---

**Note:**

As described in the [search pattern reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04.en.html), a search pattern consists of one or more conditions (“terms”), and packages match the pattern if they match all of its terms. Thus, `?upgradable ?archive(security)` is equivalent to `?and(?upgradable ?archive(security))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add ?and to combine both search parameters:

`aptitude search "?and(?upgradable ?archive(security))" --disable-columns`

Comment: The correct syntax would be `aptitude search "?and(?upgradable ?archive(security))"` but it yelds the same results anyway, i.e. it includes packages that are just from `xenial-updates` and not from `xenial-security`.

Comment: Yes - your syntax should be correct. I'm sorry - I can't test it without a connection to one of my ubuntu servers. Debian uses ?narrow for this...

Comment: The syntax in this answer should perhaps be corrected, as it currently just produces an error, but in any case I think the answer is wrong.  `aptitude search "?archive(security)" |grep xwayland` would still show the xwayland answer above.  Apparently `%t` in the search formatting does not relate to the `?archive(security)` in the aptitude search query in the way that's expected.  I haven't yet found the documentation that would explain this.